# different values for the same pointer

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I take a pointer m_room (Room *m_room in class ServicePage, where updateRoom and addService function are)

```
void ServicePage::updateRoom(QString _text)
{
    m_room = m_reservation->findRoom(_text.toInt());
    qDebug()<<m_room;
    qDebug() << m_room->m_idRoom;
}
```

from

```
Room *Reservation::findRoom(int _id)
{
    QVector<Room>::iterator iterator;
    for(iterator = mv_addRooms.begin(); iterator != mv_addRooms.end(); iterator++)
        if(iterator->m_idRoom == _id)
        {
            qDebug()<<_id;
            Room _temp = *iterator;
            return &_temp;
        }
    return null;
}
```

and answers after qDebug is allright, but when I take later qDebug answer in different function:

```
bool ServicePage::addService()
{
    qDebug()<<m_room;
    qDebug()<<m_room ->m_idRoom;
    return true;
}
```

m_room is the the same as earlier, but m_room->m_idRoom returns different value (random value), why is it that?

Thank You for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `findRoom()`, you are returning a pointer to a variable allocated on the stack.

```
        qDebug()<<_id;
        Room _temp = *iterator;
        return &_temp;
```

The memory pointed to by the return value of `findRoom()` is no longer valid when the function returns.

You can fix this by simply taking the address of the dereferenced iterator:

```
        qDebug()<<_id;
        return &*iterator;
```

That way, you are returning the pointer to the instance in your container.  Be careful if your container is a `vector<>`. If the `vector<>` grows in size, all the pointer values that had been returned earlier are now invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `_temp` as `Room &` instead of `Room`. That way, `&_temp` is a pointer to an element in mv_addRooms, not a copy of one on the stack.